# while display the result in success part using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**Data inserting in to database using ajax, while display the result in success part i am not getting the output please help me below shown my script and form code**

**code**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_basicinformation_edit',
                data: form_data,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#accordion').append('<div class="collapseOne">' +
                        '<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">' +
                        '<div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' +
                        first_name +
                        '</a></p></div></div></div>');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**form**

```
<div class="panel-heading row" id="first">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">First Name</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis"><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></div>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 profile-edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Data returned from your back-end stored inside `data` variable in your `success`. Check what is inside of this variable. I think it should be stringified JSON object. If so, dont forget to make `var response = JSON.parse(data)` and then you can you it like `response.first_name`

Comment: first of all you have store the your output in a variable and use alert to view output.

Comment: Inside success add `console.log((data)` and post your output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$('#accordion').append('<div class="collapseOne"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' +first_name+ '</a></p></div></div></div>');
```

to

```
$('#accordion').append('<div class="collapseOne"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' + data + '</a></p></div></div></div>');
```

You have to use data instead of first_name

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `#accordion` mentioned in ajax success is available in DOM or not, while you try to append the content. And data returned is available in `data` as JSON object. Parse this `data` and then get display the `first_name` from this parsed JSON object.